# when do I need to make a new controller/model for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I've been going through the http://www.railstutorial.org/book by Hartl and learn-rails by Kehoe. Both guide describe the MVC model really well, but I am having trouble understanding when to create new controllers and models and why I need to make new ones.

Throughout the tutorial they would often make new controllers and models. When I am reading through it it seemed to make sense, but when I am now trying to make a web app by myself I suddenly feel extreme lost.

I've read from other sources that when creating controllers and models,it doesn't necessarily mean for every one controller, make one model. This only confuses me more because I've always though of the MVC model as sort of a triplet that works conjunction with one another.

If you can explain the question with examples, that would be really awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analogy is quite simple.

**Models** are available for your business logic. The type of logic you may need to persist in your database, the `User` information, the `Product`'s details, a blog's `Post`.
For every such data-model, you create a **model**.

**Controllers** are available for you to relate the client-side(`Views`) with the business logic(`Model`) with or without any *preprocessing*. You may need a `UsersController` for managing sign-ups, registrations.
By this relation, you can say that a `User` model has a corresponding `Userscontrollers`.
**But that is not always the case**. Consider managing sessions, you can have a `SessionsController` which by itself manages the sign-ins, cookie handling etc; but it may still talk to `User` model(it doesn't have `Session` model).
Another example, you can have a `StaticPagesController`, and you may be using that to create the posts (from `Post` model). You may *not need* the `PostsController` at all.

Also, a controller can talk to any number of models, depending upon how your application interacts with users, and how the process flows.

The *REST* convention dictates that you have a *resource* for which you have a model, a corresponding controller, who in turns talks to different HTTP verbs, mapping them to different actions like `new`, `create`, `destroy`, `edit`, `update`. But that's just basic `CRUD`. And that is usually not what a good application is all about.